# Neighborhoods: Generator

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

**Context**

In topological groups it is more convenient to work with neighborhoods instead of opens.
In this respect one may characterize the topology by neighborhoods of the origin.
Moreover local compactness and other local concepts become straightforward this way.
For a comparison see the wikipedia article: [Characterization of Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_category_of_topological_spaces)

**Problem**

Given a plain space $\Omega$.
Consider a system $\mathcal{S}_x\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ for every $x\in\Omega$.
It shall hold $x\in S$ for every $S\in\mathcal{S}_x$.
(Take its smallest filter w.l.o.g.)
Regard [neighborhood systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_category_of_topological_spaces#Definition_via_neighbourhoods) $\mathcal{S}_x\subseteq\mathcal{N}_x$.

> Does it admit a smallest one?

For a pregiven set of opens this is possible:

Consider a system $\mathcal{S}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.
Regard topologies $\mathcal{S}\subseteq\mathcal{T}$.

Then it admits a smallest one:
$$\langle\mathcal{S}\rangle:=\bigcap_{\mathcal{S}\subseteq\mathcal{T}:\mathcal{T}\textrm{is a topology}}\mathcal{T}$$
But this construction fails above..